# Splitting large text file and sorting by content

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x

I have a large text file (~2GB) full of data. The data (sample below) gives an x, y, z coordinate, and a corresponding result on each line (there is other stuff but I don't care about it).  The single large text file is too large to be useful, so I want to split it into several smaller files.  However, I want each file to contain all the points on one y-plane.  The first few lines of the file are below:

```
 mcnp   version 6     ld=05/08/13  probid =  09/09/15 23:06:39    
 Detector Test    
 Number of histories used for normalizing tallies =    2237295223.00    


 Mesh Tally Number        14    
 photon   mesh tally.   

 Tally bin boundaries:

    X direction:   -600.00   -598.00   -596.00   ... 1236.00   1238.00   1240.00   1242.00   1244.00    1258.00   1260.00

    Y direction:      0.00     10.00     20.00     ...    740.00    750.00    760.00    770.00    780.00    790.00    800.00    810.00    820.00    830.00   840.00    850.00    860.00

    Z direction:    -60.00    -58.00    -56.00    ...  592.00    594.00    596.00    598.00    600.00    
    Energy bin boundaries: 1.00E-03 1.00E+36    

   Energy         X         Y         Z     Result     Rel Error     Volume    Rslt * Vol    
  1.000E+36  -599.000     5.000   -59.000 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 4.00000E+01 0.00000E+00    
  1.000E+36  -599.000     5.000   -57.000 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 4.00000E+01 0.00000E+00    
  1.000E+36  -599.000     5.000   -55.000 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 4.00000E+01 0.00000E+00
... and repeat forever...
```

I've truncated some of it for readability, but you get the idea.  The data I want is the four last lines.

The code currently does the following:

1. Find the line data headers (`Energy    X   Y ...`)
2. Find the y value of the first line of data
3. Add the data to a list until we find data with a different y value
4. Dump the list to a file named with the y value, delete the list
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until the end of the file.

Not all the data for each y plane is together, so if I encounter data at a y-value I've seen before, the data is appended to an existing file.

My code is below, it functions, but I feel like I could improve efficiency somewhere (execution took ~30 min).  As always, readability/style improvements are welcome, but performance is the primary goal.

```
import os

with open("meshtal", 'r') as f:
    i = 0
    coords = []
    curY = 0
    for l in f:    
        #If data header already found
        if i:
            line = l.split()
            #If this is the first line of data
            if i == 1:
                curY = line[2]
                coords.extend([(line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4])])
                i += 1
            else:
                #If data has the same y value as previous
                if curY == line[2]:
                    coords.extend([(line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4])])
                    i += 1
                #New y value, dump existing data to file
                else:    
                    fname = "Y={}.txt".format(curY)
                    #if y value has already been encountered, append existing file
                    if os.path.exists(fname):
                        with open("Y={}.txt".format(curY), 'a') as out:
                            for coord in coords:
                                out.write("{:10}{:10}{:10}{:10}\n".format(*coord))    
                    #New y value, create new file
                    else:
                        with open("Y={}.txt".format(curY), 'w') as out:
                            out.write("X         Y         Z         Result     \n")
                            for coord in coords:
                                out.write("{:10}{:10}{:10}{:10}\n".format(*coord))     
                    i = 1
                    coords = []
                    curY = line[2]
                    coords.extend([(line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4])])
                    i += 1      
        #If no data header has been found
        else:
            #If current line is data header, raise flag
            if l.lstrip().startswith("Energy         X         Y         Z     Result     Rel Error     Volume    Rslt * Vol"):
                i += 1
                print "found start"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of nesting going on here. That's generally harder to read and parse, especially when you could actually make liberal use of `continue` instead. `continue` will skip to the next iteration of the loop, ignoring all remaining code. So you could move your check for the header file to the top and avoid indentation:

```
for l in f:    
    #If data header not found
    if not i:
        if l.lstrip().startswith("Energy         X         Y         Z     Result     Rel Error     Volume    Rslt * Vol"):
            i += 1
            print "found start"
        continue
```

Also `i` is a terrible variable here. `i` is initially being used to indicate that a line has been found, then seems to become an index value. Instead I would initialise `i` as your index once this line is found, but use a named boolean like `found_header` instead. Something that's clear could remove the need for comments since `if found_header` is self explanatory. Likewise, I think you should use `line` instead of `l`. You do use `line` to replace `l` later. `l` in particular can look like a one or an upper case letter i, so it's not clear.

Also there's nothing wrong with doing `line = line.split()` since you don't need the original value of line after this part.

I'd move `i+=1` out of the `if else`, since it happens in both cases anyway. You can do it at the start of the loop anyway if you just initialise `i` as `0`. Once again, I'd use continue to save a level of nesting, like so:

```
#If this is the first line of data
i += 1
if i == 1:
    curY = line[2]
    coords.extend([(line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4])])
    continue

#If data has the same y value as previous
if curY == line[2]:
    coords.extend([(line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4])])
    continue

#New y value, dump existing data to file
fname = "Y={}.txt".format(curY)
```

Also append mode will still create a new empty file if none exists, so you don't need to check for it. Just always open with `'a'` and then write your data. You can just check if the file exists beforehand and store the result as a boolean.

```
#if y value has already been encountered, append existing file
new_file = os.path.exists(fname)
with open("Y={}.txt".format(curY), 'a') as out:
    if new_file:
        out.write("X         Y         Z         Result     \n")
    for coord in coords:
        out.write("{:10}{:10}{:10}{:10}\n".format(*coord))
```

So here's how I'd put together the whole thing:

```
import os

header = "Energy         X         Y         Z     Result     Rel Error     Volume    Rslt * Vol"

with open("meshtal", 'r') as f:
    header_found = False
    i = 0
    coords = []
    curY = 0

    for line in f:    
        if not header_found:
            if line.lstrip().startswith(header):
                print "found start"
                header_found = True
            continue

        line = line.split()
        i += 1

        #If this is the first line of data
        if i == 1:
            curY = line[2]
            coords.extend([(line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4])])
            continue

        #If data has the same y value as previous
        if curY == line[2]:
            coords.extend([(line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4])])
            continue

        #New y value, dump existing data to file
        filename = "Y={}.txt".format(curY)
        new_file = os.path.exists(fname)
        with open("Y={}.txt".format(curY), 'a') as out:
            if new_file:
                out.write("X         Y         Z         Result     \n")
            for coord in coords:
                out.write("{:10}{:10}{:10}{:10}\n".format(*coord))    

        i = 1
        coords = []
        curY = line[2]
        coords.extend([(line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4])])
```

Comment: It seems like, since the data is particularly un-ordered, that I end up switching between y-values a lot.  Is it worth leaving each output file open? (open it on the first instance of a y-value, then close them all at the end)

Comment: Will you have a lot of them to open and write a lot of data? I'd have to check how large those objects would be if you were to do that. I'm actually not sure.

Comment: There are 90 files, and I'm opening and closing each one several times a minute, and the file size goes up between 40 - 70 KB each time.

Comment: @wnnmaw From what I can see that would save a lot of time, yes. I think it'd be best to store as a dictionary of `curY: open(file)`. However you can't use `with` in that case, so you should make sure to handle file closing properly. Do you want me to add a section to my answer about this?

Comment: Storing the files in a dict is a good idea, I can implement that.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems that last batch of coords is never written out.
- *Not* using `for l in f`, but explicitly calling `f.readline()` significantly simplifies the flow:

  ```
  with open("meshtal", 'r') as f:
      while not f.readline.lstrip().startswith("..."):
          pass
      # Header found. The rest are data points
      ...
  ```
- Before first data point is read, `curY` is undefined. It seems logical to initialize it to `None`, and abandon the first/not-first line detection (recall that `None` compares unequal to anything):

  ```
      line = f.readline().split()
      if curY == line[2]:
          # Y is the same, keep going
      else:
          # dump if necessary; reinitialize coords and curY
  ```
- Since `coords.extend()` is needed regardless of `curY` changes, it is better take it out of conditional.

Putting it all together:

```
    with open("meshtal", 'r') as f:
        while not f.readline.lstrip().startswith("..."):
            pass

        curY = None
        coords = []

        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                dump(curY, coords) # takes care of the last batch
                break

            line = line.split()
            if curY != line[2]:
                dump(curY, coords)
                curY = line[2]
                coords = []

            coords.extend([(line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4])])
```